# Tiktok marketing api authorization "Timestamp has expired." code 40115 on all calls

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, oauth, tiktok, tiktok-api

I'm trying to get a refresh_token from the TikTok oauth2 endpoint, but for some reason, it returns

```
  "code" => 40115
  "message" => "Timestamp has expired."
```

What I do is I take the auth link from inside the app admin panel, and then return back to the redirect URL and make a call to the open_api/v1.3/oauth2/creator_token/?business=tt_user endpoint with the client_id, client_secret, grant_type, auth_code, but I always get the same message. And also, if I check the header, it says an instant date. How come?

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $accessTokenUrl = 'https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/oauth2/creator_token/?business=tt_user';
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post($accessTokenUrl, [
        "client_id" => env('TIKTOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        "client_secret" => env('TIKTOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "auth_code" => $request['auth_code']
    ]);
    if($response->successful()) {
        dump($response->headers());
        dd($response->json());
    } else {
        dump($response->headers());
        dd($response->json());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please point us to the documentation for that specific endpoint you are using there?

Comment: https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1737586583649281

Comment: Can't see anything directly wrong. Not sure if they have an extended explanation for error codes anywhere (can't use their site search without logging in, apparently.)

Comment: https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1737172488964097

Comment: Sounds like your auth code might be to old. Not sure what exactly _"What I do is I take the auth link from inside the app admin panel"_ is supposed to mean? If this is not a URL you _created_ in that moment, to get the whole process started, then I guess that might be the reason?

Comment: Hi , we are getting the same error , `auth code is always expired` , any progress on this?

Comment: @tknkrtl no progress yet, think it's actually not possible to resolve it yet.

Comment: Does the v2 "TikTok account holder authorization URL" work for you?  I log into a personal tiktok account and then hit that url and i always get "You don't have permission to access "http://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize?" on this server."